# What is client side MVC and how is it implemented in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application

Recently gone through many articles explaining single page application. But i am very much confused about the architecture or rather how it works.

1. There is some thing new called client side MVC implemented by using javascript. Till now i had seen server side MVC architecture. What is this client side MVC?
2. Where does the client side MVC files are hosted. Is it hosted along with server files similar to typical web application.
3. What is the role of server side java script like node.js.
4. What is the flow from end to end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Client side MVC means that a MVC framework is built entirely on the client side. So the server only delivers data to the application. The binding of the data to the models happens client side.

An example of a framework that implements this principle is [AngularJs](http://angularjs.org/)
Another one is [Ember](http://emberjs.com/).

Node on the server side has nothing to do with client side MVC. The data delivered to the webapp could be delivered by any technology capable of doing that.

Nodejs is often used to run client side development tools and run tests. For example, the development server that comes with the [AngularJs tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) is build on node.