# Where does HTML.RenderAction is executed?

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

I tried to find a clear answer, but could not.
Where does the helper method such as Html.RenderAction() and Html.Partial() are executed? at the server or the client side?
Is the razor code, executed locally?

If on the server, is there a client-side alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor runs on the server, and generates HTML. This HTML is then sent to the client.

If you want to render or change HTML on the client, you'll need to do so using JavaScript. You could for example [serialize your model into JSON and store that in a JavaScript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344089/how-to-get-json-object-from-razor-model-object-in-javascript):

```
<script>
    var myModel = @JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject);
</script>
```

Then you can access `myModel` from JavaScript to do whatever you want, for example bind it to a [clientside MVC framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653014/what-is-client-side-mvc-and-how-is-it-implemented-in-javascript) such as Angular or Ember.

Comment: so any code with @{} will be executed on the sever?

Comment: Will this slow up the page loading? is there any resource to read about how it works? because I am concerned about the performance

Comment: Razor is fast enough.